# RedirectToLocal() goes to a different url

Tags: asp.net-mvc

The following code snippet is from my ASP.NET MVC 5 application:

```
   public ActionResult Ask(string id) {
        if (!this.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) {
            string retUrl = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
            return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account", new { returnUrl = retUrl });
        }
        ...
   }
```

The idea is, if the user has not yet logged in, he will be taken to the login page and subsequently be returned back to this "Ask" page.

When the user enters, for example, `http://example.com/Home/Ask/12345678`, method Ask() gets invoked with the correct value for id. The user is now redirected to the login page.

After Login() code in AccountController successfully authenticates the user, it calls ReturnToLocal(), passing in the url that we expect (`http://example.com/Home/Ask/12345678`). However, instead of invoking the Ask() method , ASP .NET somehow ends up invoking Index() method.

Appreciate your help in understanding why my redirection is broken. Regards.

Comment: Please put the Login action method code too. Then only i have able understand what happening

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you did not provide us neither the `Login` action method nor `RedirectToLocal` method I am assuming you are using the `AccountController` from MVC5 template.
If so

```
private ActionResult RedirectToLocal(string returnUrl)
{
      if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
      {
        return Redirect(returnUrl);
      }
      return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

You can see that `RedirectToLocal` method checkes if the `returnUrl` parameter is 'localUrl'.
If not it does invoke Index.
In your Ask method you are passing  `string retUrl = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri` as `returnUrl` which is not local (starts with http://)!

Try `string retUrl = Request.Url.PathAndQuery`