# Where is value of "returnUrl" set in MVC 5? It always takes me to /Home/Index

Tags: authentication, asp.net-mvc-5

It is null everywhere I find it during runtime.

I've got all the bells and whistles that halfway come with MVC 5 Template VS 2013.
I figured out all the extra Indentity and DataAnnotations stuff and it all works. (40 files and 5 tables later sheez).

But when signing in it all follows through but the registered user gets redirected to a "Home/Index" page, the default page that comes with template. I want them to get somewhere else, like "PickLocation".

Now nowhere in my code can I find "/Home/Index" referenced by searching the entire solution. In Web.config the authentication mode is set to "none".

*Here is my Register link in _LoginPartial.cshtml:*

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "registerLink", style = "color:white;" })</li>
```

Somehow it heads for the HomeController.
*Here is the Home Controller ActionResult that I can put a breakpoint to prove it was hit:*

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Notice = "This is coming from Home Controller";
        return View();
    }
```

In my AccountController the Login ActionResult returns "null" for the "returnURL" parameter. On Success (which is what happens) it goes to "return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);" Where is this set? Nowhere can I find value of returnURL or where it is set and I don't want to continue to end up on the MS default Home/Index page that comes with the template. Log Out also goes to Home/Index page. I set IIS default page to "PickLocation.cshtml" but no luck

*Here is the Login Action code here:*

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(model);
    }

    // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
    // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
    var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
    switch (result)
    {
        case SignInStatus.Success:
            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
```

Edit:
*I just remembered someone is going to ask if this is set in RouteConfig.cs. .. .no it's not.*

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        //routes.MapRoute(
        //    name: "Default",
        //    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        //    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        //);

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Stores", action = "PickLocation", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

    }
```

Here is the AccountController Login GET "method"

```
// GET: /Account/Login
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
{
    ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
    return View();
}
```

But the question still stands: "where in the heck is the project/solution getting the "/home/index" that it sends me back to after registering or logging off? No where does the "/home/index" show up in a search.

Comment: The link should be `routeValues: new { returnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }` assuming your have set the value in the `Login` GET method - you have not shown the code so not sure what you have done. But the link you have shown is for a `Register()` method, but you have shown code for a `Login()` method

Answer (score 2):

Oh my gosh, if it was a snake it would have bit me.
I was searching for "Home/Index". I didn't think that it would be separate as in "Action, Controller". sheez.

This [StackOverFlow question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27560840/redirecttolocal-goes-to-a-different-url) showed me the light. I searched in my project for "private ActionResult RedirectToLocal" and I got this Action and down at the bottom was "return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");" Pretty sure I can change it there. I hope my misery will help some other newby like me.

```
    private ActionResult RedirectToLocal(string returnUrl)
    {
        if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
        {
            return Redirect(returnUrl);
        }
             return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
```